# How to handle non-English accented characters using a physical keyboard in an Android app written in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey, diacritics

Non-English languages often have diacritics (glyphs added to letters to alter the letters), such as the circumflex accent in French as in`â` or `ê`. Those characters are generally obtained by first hitting a dead key on the keyboard, such as <kbd>^</kbd>, followed by the letter on which we want to apply the diacritic. So, to obtain `â`, one has to press <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> to see `â` in the edit control.

When writing an Android app in Delphi using FireMonkey, the handling of those diacritics has always been problematic when a physical keyboard is attached to the Android device, whether it is via USB or Bluetooth.

For example, prior to Delphi 10.4.x, in a `TEdit` or a `TMemo`, pressing <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> would give `^a` instead of the expected `â`. Note that applications not written in Delphi are not exhibiting this peculiar problem.

As of Delphi 10.4.x, the problem has been fixed for `TEdit`, but unfortunately `TMemo` is still plagued with the problem. Of course, if one is not using a physical keyboard, everything works perfectly. However, as I am trying to write an application that will support a physical keyboard, particularly in Samsung DeX mode, this poses a serious problem.

I am therefore asking for help in perhaps overriding the key handling of the `TMemo`, perhaps using the `OnKeyDown` event, to fix this problem that prevents my app from being used by non-English users.

Knowing that when pressing <kbd>^</kbd>, in the `OnKeyDown` event we get `Key = $0` and `KeyChar = 710`, I managed to intercept the diacritic and insert the accented letter, but I have not been able to remove the diacritic so pressing <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> gives `^â` in the `TMemo`. I can't figure out how to remove the `^` in front of the `â`.

```
...
private
  { Private declarations }
  IsDeadKey: Boolean;
  DeadKey: Char;

...
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if IsDeadKey then
  begin
    if (Ord(DeadKey) = 710) then
    begin
      case KeyChar of
        'a': KeyChar := 'â';
        'e': KeyChar := 'ê';
      end;
      IsDeadKey := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      KeyChar := DeadKey;
      IsDeadKey := False;
    end;
  end
  else
    if (Key = $0) and (Ord(KeyChar) = 710) then
    begin
      IsDeadKey := True;
      DeadKey := KeyChar;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know anything about FMX or Android or smartphones, but does it help to add `KeyChar := #0` to your last conditional?

Comment: Oh do I feel stupid! @AndreasRejbrand, you are 100% right! I should have known that! You have no idea how long I tried to solve this and the solution was so simple. It works perfectly now! Thank you so much for such insightfulness!

Comment: Thanks to @AndreasRejbrand, this is a "patch" to fix a bug in FireMonkey's TMemo. I wonder if someone came up with a more elegant solution by either patching the source or deriving a TMemo class that fixes the problem?